# High CPU load because high CPU time for sys

Tags: mysql, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage, galera

I am using MariaDB galera cluster with two nodes + one node for arbiter. My system has 24 core CPU. I am getting stuck with CPU bound. Sometimes, my system consume CPU time to 1000% and CPU load get above 16. `mysqld` process consume about 200-300% and normally CPU load is about 2-3.

I am monitoring process list. I don't know why some system process like md126_raid1, irqbalance... suddenly consume CPU so much. There is nothing in `/var/log/messages` or `dmesg`. I am running multi master on galera so there is some conflict in error messages of mysqld but I think it is natural and mysqld not consume CPU so much.

Do you know any ideas for my problem ?

P/S: Sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: How's the IO? I usually use tool like 'dstat', 'iostat', 'htop' to analysis the problem. You may try 'dstat' to find the 'ini' and 'csw' are high or not.

Comment: I have restarted mysqld service. The problem has gone. It will disappear in one week. I remember the analysis result is very high context switch. I don't notice ini value. I will collect it when the problem come back again.